# I ported my midlet to Blackberry and I can't assign a listener to the ESCAPE key

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

Here is some of the code in my midlet:

the *addKeyListener* method presents an error as the function is not recognized.

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.KeyListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Keypad;

public class PhraZApp extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet implements ActionListener{

public PhraZApp {
 addKeyListener (new KeyPadListener());
}


 protected void keyPressed(int key) {
    System.out.println(key);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyEvent());
}

 public final class KeyPadListener implements KeyListener {

    public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {

        return false;
    }

    public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time) {
        if (Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE == Keypad.key(keycode)) {
                  System.out.println("key: " + keycode);
        return true;
    }
            //let the system to pass the event to another listener.
    return false;
    }

    public boolean keyUp(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public boolean keyRepeat(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    public boolean keyStatus(int keycode, int time) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

The keyPressed action is not heard by any of those listeners.

Ive been told to add the keylistner to a GUI component, but none that I try it with accept it. 
Furthermore, one of the possible issues is that the addKeyListener method is not declared, but in that case I don't know how to declare it.

If i change *extends javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet* to *extends UiApplication*, the *addKeyListener* becomes accepted but the entire midlet falls to a RuntimeErrorException.

How can I get my Midlet to hear the escape key? I have searched through many forums and none of the suggestions have worked so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a LWUIT question? It is tagged LWUIT but its unclear from your explanation if you used LWUIT? If you have just place a Command in Form.setBackCommand().

Comment: I am using LWUIT. How do I interact with that line? What I mean is, in what context do I use that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a LWUIT `Command` and assign it to the parent form using the `setBackCommand` method. You can handle the command event like you handle every other command in LWUIT. E.g. through a command listener or even just by subclassing it and overriding `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`.

Comment: upvote 100 times! Todah rabah chaver!
I will write in the answer how I solved this more specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Shai pointing me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9501124/839601), I solved it.

Here is how I did it.

```
Command backCommand = new Command("",Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE);
form.setBackCommand(backCommand);
```

then

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    if (evt.getCommand().getId() ==Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE){
        //execution code  
    }
```

I didn't try, but if I had included text in the command I imagine it would appear as such when I push the menu button. The important thing is that I finally got the MIDlet to hear out the escape button after MANY hours of trying and searching for solutions.